# IllegalAccessException on HQL statement (using ManyToOne)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am dynamically building HQL statements for a project but for some reason I have having issues with the following:

```
FROM Team m WHERE m.location.city= :location.city
```

The Team and Location both have `@Entity` annotations and the Team references the Location:

```
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, optional=true, targetEntity=Location.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="locationId", referencedColumnName="id")
    private Location location;
```

Location city:

```
    @Column(name="city", nullable=true)
    private String city;
```

Creation of query (error of like):

```
Query query = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager().createQuery(statement);
```

The error:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [cpr] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.lookupProperty(HqlSqlWalker.java:591)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.addrExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4932)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.expr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1260)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.exprOrSubquery(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4639)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.comparisonExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4114)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2096)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.whereClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:794)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:595)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:299)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:247)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:190)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1800)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:342)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy42.createQuery(Unknown Source)
```

I have also tried joining instead:

```
FROM Team m LEFT JOIN m.location as g WHERE g.city= :location.city
```

Comment: how did you bind the parameter `location.city` ? can you that code also? I think the issue is related to that.

Comment: I added additional details. Thanks!

Comment: How can you be sure `parameters` doesn't contain null ?

Comment: The error is being thrown from the createQuery method (also, using the debugger my parameters are 'location.city'=>"St. Louis")

Comment: then entityManagerFactory could be null. cannot be sure because I don't know the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! Apparently the value cannot have `.` in it.

Previous HQL:

```
FROM Team m WHERE m.location.city= :location.city
```

Fixed HQL:

```
FROM Team m WHERE m.location.city= :city
```

(Also while fixing this I found out `-` does not work either.)

Answer (score 0):

It's a `java.lang.NullPointerException`

- Check `entityManagerFactory` is injected correctly and is not null.
- Check that the query parameters are not null

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sadly this didn't solve the issue, I am at a loss. Thanks

Comment: @jrquick: I think the code that you've added is not enough. It is not clear how you set the parameters and how you build the session factory .etc

Comment: The issue had to do with the dot in the parameters key. Never knew this was an issue